# AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer returns -50

Tags: ios, audio-streaming

I got a filled buffer from the **recording queue**, then I tried to enqueue it to a **playing queue**, the AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer returns -50.
Then I Alloc a **new** AudioQueueBuffer and copy the recorded buffer's data to it, and enqueue the **new** buffer to the playing queue, it succeeded.
Could you tell me why can't I enqueue a recorded buffer to a playing queue?
**Thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody answers...ok...

```
AudioQueueAllocBuffer(<b>queue</b>, buffersize, &<b>buffer</b>);
```

When alloc a `AudioQueueBuffer`, you must specify a `AudioQueue`, that means the audio queue **own** the buffer allocated, you cannot enqueue the buffer in another queue...